# Most likely way to find Nether wart if my Nether fortress doesn't have any?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing on my multiplayer server on 1.18. We've found one Nether fortress, but were really unlucky cause it has no chests or Nether wart, just Blazes and Wither skeletons.  I really want Nether wart so I can brew potions.

Would it be more likely for me to find another Nether fortress with Nether wart, or to find a Bastion Remnant with Nether wart?  I ask because you sort of head in opposite directions to find each one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People is in opposite directions because.. it's not possible to say. They are both random generated structures, nobody will know what you're gonna find first.

Probably Nether fortresses have higher chances to give you [Nether wart](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Wart), because it can be found also in chests:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either way, you need to keep exploring to find one of those two structures as warts cannot be obtained anywhere else that I am aware of. As the other answer states, a fortress is more likely to have them, but you can't be certain which one you'll run into first. Good luck!